# getting req.body ReadableStream in nextjs14 app routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js14

I'm trying to get req.body in api but getting ReadableStream.

my code looks like:

```
// src/app/api/posts/route.js

export async function POST(req, res) {
    console.log('Post request received');
    console.log(req.body);


    return Response.json({
        "success": true,
        "data": req.body,
        "message": "Fetched successfully"
    });
}
```

expected

```
//console log
{'title':'test blog'}
```

but getting

```
// console log
ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }
```

its on nextjs 14.0.4 and app routing

Comment: By the way, I'm making request from postman, and header "Content-Type":"application/json"

Comment: I think using `async/await` might work `await Response.json()`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use express.js here for a backend fetch? Because if so, you can use something like this as your path:

```
import express from "express";

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/WhateverYouWantAsPath", (req, res) => {
console.log("Post Request Received!")
console.log(req.body)
})
```

Here your post request will be parsed and you can then use all your request data.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The question is tagged as `next.js` and makes no mention of express.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they first didn't have next.js mentioned but I could be wrong and just didn't see it. My fault!